# Setting paths in Fish like in Bash?

Tags: bash, fish

I've got this in my bash_profile, and I can't figure out the equivalent in Fish:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Dev/ark/bin
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin/
export PATH=$PATH:~/i386-elf/bin/
export GOPATH=~/Dev/gocode/
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

How do I do that in my fish configuration file? I've tried

```
set PATH $PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: I fixed my fish config to be

```
set -x GOPATH ~/Dev/gocode
set -U fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths ~/Dev/ark/bin ~/bin/ ~/i386-elf/bin $GOPATH/bin
```

But I dunno if you want to close the question or if anyone wants to submit an answer or...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064053/add-a-relative-path-to-path-on-fish-startup

Comment: Apparently that adds to the $PATH, what about the $GOPATH one?

Comment: How does it fail? Is `$GOPATH` defined in your fish conf file? Is there an error message?

Comment: It doesn't really give me any errors, but when I ran make on a go project it moaned about my `$GOPATH`

Comment: Okay took me a little more googling on the specifics, but Rinzind got me far enough to get $PATH working, and I've fixed my $GOPATH too.

Answer (score 3):

To set a custom environmental variable it appears that you use `-x` and then the path. For a persistent environmental variable, you have to set the `fish_user_paths`, which will append the given paths to your $PATH.

<sup>path<sup>path<sup>path<sup>path</sup></sup></sup></sup>

```
set -x GOPATH ~/Dev/gocode
set -U fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths ~/Dev/ark/bin ~/bin/ ~/i386-elf/bin $GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: If that's in your config.fish, your fish_user_paths variable will grow and grow and grow. Instead of appending every time you launch a shell, do `set -U fish_user_path ~/Dev/ark/bin ~/bin/ ~/i386-elf/bin $GOPATH/bin`